# Suppress results from generated code

Tags: c#, auto-generate

I have a project created with "Suppress results from generated code" checked in its properties. When I add a service reference, the proxy class (reference.cs) that is autogenerated adds the following attribute:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "3.0.0.0")]
```

When I compile in release mode, as I have enabled generation of xml comments, I am getting warnings as none of the proxy methods are commented. To my understanding, I shouldn´t get that as I have the suppress of autogenerated code.

In addition, the reference.cs class is not clscompliant.

Do anybody has idea of how to solve this without using pragma disable/enable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The "Suppress results from generated code" option is for code analysis only. To suppress warnings from the compiler, you'll have to use pragma disable.